# Command + W has stopped working for python app

Tags: catalina, shortcut, python

I'm working on a matplotlib Python application to draw graphs (MacOS Catalina 10.15.5). I was able to close the window using Command + W but recently that doesn't seem to work. The shortcut works with other applications like Firefox or Finder. Any way I can fix this?

Comment: What's the key command shown by Close in the File Menu?

Comment: The app window doesn't have any menus on the menu bar.